# Do not show iMessages on iPhone when using Messages on Macbook

Tags: messages, iphone

Is it possible to somehow temporarily disable iMessages on iPhone when using Messages app on Macbook, I don't like my iPhone to vibrate and wake up on the table all the time when someone sends me a message when I'm chatting through Messages app on Macbook?

I notices, that sometimes it vibrates for 1-2 messages and then it stops for the rest of conversation, but now it's showing almost every message on iPhone

Comment: I found out of you keep the messages app open, not minimalized - you will get less notification on phone because they are recognized as read by the macbook.

Comment: I have Messages app always open, I do not use minimize, just switching to other applications.. but it's still unread until I switch to Messages app.. when I'm actively chatting in Messages, it's not popping out on iPhone (maybe sometimes)

Answer (score 1):

The function of iMessage is to push your messages to all devices. To turn this off, go to Settings > Messages and disable iMessage. However, this is certainly not automatic, and may remove your cache of message from your iPhone.

As a commenter mentioned, keeping the app open on the iPhone will minimize your annoyance.